# Flutter Error. Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

Hey I want to start learning flutter and I bought a course but when I try to run the **auto-generated app** I get the following error:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Flutter\untitled\build\app\intermediates\navigation_json\debug\navigation.json (The system cannot find the file specified)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 31s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Flutter\untitled\build\app\intermediates\navigation_json\debug\navigation.json (The system cannot find the file specified)



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I saw other people talk about this here but the solution that worked for them didn't work for me.

**Here are the things I've tried:**
./gralew clean or./gradlew build
/flutter clean
reinstalling flutter and android studio from scratch.
deleting the gradle files and the build files.
switching to another laptop.

I will be very grateful if you guys can help me.
Best Regards,
-Roee Hovav.
*Peace!*

Comment: Have you try to remove the android folder and the flutter commande : flutter create .

Comment: Yeah I did try doing that...

Comment: Didn't help at all

Comment: is that you change Pubspec file ? like add Assets or font ?

Comment: I didn't add anything.

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio make sure you have the latest version installed, and everything is updated then go ahead and open the Flutter project and trying building it from Android Studio

Comment: I've installed everything today so I think everything is updated.

Comment: I will still check it but what are the lastest versions for everything? And I tried to build the app through android studio and that is the error I get...

Answer (score 0):

I found the similar error but for me is missing of androidmanifest.xml and I have fixed it

For me I have deleted the android folder and run command "flutter create ."
then I got another of errors about **"SdkMinVersion"** and **"Flutter multidex handling is disabled."** and fixed it step by step

Anyway I have found this solution after I have fixed and hope it will help you
--> changing gradle version as the link below
https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/380